# Angular2 set strokeColor in SebmGoogleMapCircle - TypeScript

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript, google-maps-markers

I want to set stroke color for google map circles.I'm using the code:

```
<sebm-google-map-circle  fillColor="rgba(243, 73, 71, 1)" fillOpacity=1.0 strokeColor="red" strokeWeight=250 [latitude]="latB" [longitude]="lngB" [radius]="250000"  ></sebm-google-map-circle>
```

But fillcolor is working but strokecolor is not working.Please help anyone to solve the issue.

Refferd Docs: https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/index/SebmGoogleMapCircle-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

problem is

```js
 fillColor="rgba(243, 73, 71, 1)"
```

you should not use rgba for fillColor

```js
fillColor="#some color"
```

and use fillOpacity  for opacity